# How to check whether the file belongs to My Drive or Team Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Is there any less time consuming way to check if file's Root Directory is "My Drive" or "Team Drive"?

I have tried using `file.getParents();` and then iterating through every parent and finally to Root, but this is way too time consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a file is in Team Drive, the owner is the Team Drive and not any particular user.

You can perform a check for ownership on the file and if it is set to null, the file is likely inside Team Drive.

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("fileID");
if (file.getOwner() === null) {
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. I will try this and update you. BTW I got this iteration idea from your blog [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/19946-get-folder-path-of-files) only. Thanks for all blogs and help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with the `Drive` advanced service, you can directly query for Team Drive information:

Example:

```
function getTeamDriveId(fileId) {
  const options = {
    fields: "id,title,teamDriveId",
  };
  const file = Drive.Files.get(fileId, options);
  return file.teamDriveId;
}
```

For a file not in a Team Drive, the above id will be false-y.

There are several metadata fields to query that are only present or absent for Team Drive items. It is important to note which API version you use, as there are changes to resource names between 2 and 3. It is also important to use strict comparisons when testing the presence of absence of `Boolean` fields, or other fields which may be false-y.

Absent:

- ownerNames
- owners
- writersCanShare
- shared
- permissions
- folderColorRgb
- ownedByMe

Present:

- teamDriveId
- hasAugmentedPermissions
- capabilities/canMoveTeamDriveItem
- capabilities/canReadTeamDrive
- trashingUser
- trashedDate

References:

- [Enable advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Drive `File` metadata (v2)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files#resource)
- [Partial responses](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/performance#partial)

Comment: Thanks tehhowch. I can use Advance Service as well. I will check the answer and update you.

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi I checked the example code :) I figure it is one of the more useful checks, as a logical question after "Is this a Team Drive item" is "Which Team Drive?", and with that code you have both answers :)